# Function , exponential distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

Let $X \sim Exp(2)$ ,X has therefore density function  $f_X(x) = 2e^{-2x}$ , $x\geq 0$ if we let  $g(x) = 1- e^{-2x} $.We now want to find the probability density function for $V = g(X)= 1-e^{-2x}$ .The inverse function  $g^{-1}(v) = -\ln(1-v/2)$. The distribution function for $X$ is given by  $F_X(x) =  1-e^{-2x}$ for this reason we get:

$F_V(v) = P(V \leq v) = P(1-e^{-2x} \leq v) = P(X \leq -\ln(1-v)/2 =  F_X(-\ln(1-v)/2) = v$

my question is how you get the last equality that is,  $F_X(-\ln(1-v)/2) = v$
I don't "see" what made it equal to $v$ can someone fill in any detail or explain ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that $F_X(t)=1-e^{-2t}$. Substitute $-\frac{\ln(1-v)}{2}$ for $t$. So we want $1-e^{\ln(1-v)}$. This is $1-(1-v)$, since $e^{\ln u}=u$.

Comment: ofcourse sorry for asking this question...so easy

Comment: Yes, in retrospect it is straightforward, but there are many "easy" things that I do not readily see.  The result (which generalizes) is very important for simulations. It gives a way of producing pseudo-random exponentially distributed numbers from the usual generator that produces uniform on $[0,1]$ pseudo-random numbers.